# unloadMovie is not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am having a similar issue to this post except that I am using only AS2 at the moment.

[AS2 .swf loadmovie() and unloadmovie() fail when nested inside an AS3 .swf container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044713/as2-swf-loadmovie-and-unloadmovie-fail-when-nested-inside-an-as3-swf-contai)

I call a swf file to load into a loader like this music_mc.loadMovie("music/song.swf").

When I unload the movie clip like this: music_mc.unloadMovie() and try and load it again, it does not want to load again.

Anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to sort this out! I had two frames in my music swf and not sending it to the correct frame to start playing the music! Chop! :)